# should src folder be created in golang go1.17

Tags: go

I am starting off with golang according to some document it mentions $GOPATH default should have `bin  pkg  src` directories.
When a I do `go get github.com/astaxie/beedb` there no src folder created and the source goes and sits in `$GOPATH/pkg//mod/github.com/astaxie/beedb@v0.0.0-20141221130223-1732292dfde4/`

according to documentation the it should be in src folder

I am using golang go1.17. Has something changed in newer versions or am I refering old doc.

Comment: GOPATH is long obsolete. Use [modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to create `src` folder under `$GOPATH`
With [Go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules), Go projects are no longer confined to `$GOPATH`

Don't confuse the project level /src directory with the /src directory Go used to use  for its workspaces, but please note
["Since Go 1.14, module support is considered ready for production use, and all users are encouraged to migrate to modules from other dependency management systems "](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

please check below links
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manually create the sub-folders in `$GOPATH`. When you run `go get`, go will handle everything for you. So if there is no `src` folder, you can just leave it.

The `src` folder was basically for package management before [Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) (enabled by default since go 1.13). You don't really need this now.